# How do I open an iOS simulator local .realm file in Realm Studio

Tags: ios, realm, ios-simulator

Using realm browser I was able to print the path of the `.realm` file in the simulator and open it from the terminal (macOS) using:

```
open /Users/.../long path/.../default.realm
```

This doesn't seem to work with Realm Studio (it still tries to open with Realm Browser). Realm Studio has an "Open a local Realm" option on the splash screen, but that takes me to macOS's awful finder, which doesn't allow me to type in a path (Windows +1). Maybe I don't properly understand macOS's file structure, but it doesn't appear to be showing one of the directories I would need to navigate into to find the `.realm`

Does Realm Studio have a cli tool or cli method of opening?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The fact that Realm Studio does not yet open files in response to the open AppleEvent (sent by double-clicking on a Realm file in the finder, or using `open` on a .realm file) is a known issue.

In the mean time, you can open it via Realm Studio's Open panel by first copying the path, typing `/` when the Open panel is showing, then pasting the copied path into the text field that has appeared.